# Using if condition to assign True or False to gather_facts in Ansible doesnt work

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-facts

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ run_on_node|default('mysql_cluster_sql[0]')}}"
  connection: "{% if migrated is defined and migrated == 'yes' %}local{% else %}ssh{% endif %}" # This works as we are assigning non boolean value
  gather_facts: "{% if migrated is defined and migrated == 'yes' %}false{% else %}true{% endif %}" #This doesnt work well
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

Inventory File:

```
[mysql_cluster_sql]
10.200.1.191 migrated=yes
```

The variable has the value as true and false based on condition but even when gather_facts is false, it gathers the facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify and fix the condition. Use the default value. This will cover both tests, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: "{{ (migrated|default('no') == 'yes')|ternary(false, true) }}"
  tasks:
    - meta: noop
```

will gather facts without the variable *migrated* defined

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

, or when the variable is set to other value than 'yes'

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e migrated=no

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

When the variable is set to 'yes' no facts will be gathered

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e migrated=yes

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************
```

---

**Jinja**

If you insist on [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/) the playbook below gives the same results

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: "{% if migrated|default('no') == 'yes' %}
                 false
                 {% else %}
                 true
                 {% endif %}"
  tasks:
    - meta: noop
```

---

**Boolean**

You can further simplify the test by explicit conversion to [Boolean](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: "{{ (migrated|default('no')|bool)|ternary(false, true) }}"
  tasks:
    - meta: noop
```

---

**Truthy/Falsy**

Make sure you understand how Boolean conversion and testing work. See results of the tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "True"
      loop: [yes, Yes, true, True, xxx]
      when: item|bool

    - debug:
        msg: "False"
      loop: [no, No, false, False, xxx]
      when: not item|bool

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|bool|ternary(True, False) }}"
      loop: [yes, Yes, true, True, xxx,
             no, No, false, False, xxx]

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|ternary(True, False) }}"
      loop: [yes, Yes, true, True, xxx,
             no, No, false, False, xxx]
```

---

Q: *"**Passing the variable 'migrated' from within the inventory does not work.**"*

A: You're right. It seems that the inventory variables are not available at the time *gather_facts* is running. Use [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) as a workaround. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - setup:
      when: (migrated|default('no')|bool)|ternary(false, true)
```

Comment: This following suggestion works for me,

`shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: "{{ (migrated|default('no') == 'yes')|ternary(false, true) }}"
  tasks:
    - meta: noop`

But only when i pass the variable via command line with -e option.
But i am passing the variable migrated from within the inventory which is not working well. It gathers facts even when its 'yes'

Comment: You're right. I wasn't aware of this limitation. Use setup as a workaround. I've added the details in the answer.

Comment: I understood the logic now and everything is now working well for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`gather_facts` will be evaluted before the play loop has started so ansible cannot know which group/host var it should load in this case. The problem is exactly the same for the `connection` attribute.

I only see one way to fulfill your requirement by gathering facts explicitly and setting the connection for each host. Ini format does not play well with this for the inventory so I transformed to yaml. I also modified your default `hosts` expression in playbook so that it directly get the host name from inventory. You can keep yours if it suits your needs if you wish.

Inventory:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    mysql_cluster_sql:
      hosts:
        10.200.1.191:
          migrated: yes
      vars:
        ansible_connection: "{{ migrated | default(false) | bool | ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
```

Playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ run_on_node | default(groups['mysql_cluster_sql'][0]) }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: gather_facts if not migrated
      setup:
      when: not (migrated | default(false) | bool)

    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

    - debug:
        var: ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

Comment: How do i keep the inventory file in the same format because there are many more aprox 60 groups.

Comment: Put the `ansible_connection` varialbe inside a `group_vars/mysql_cluster_sql.yml` file adjacent to your inventory. See [organizing group and host vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)

Comment: Is this possible to use in the playbook itself? 
`gather_facts: "{{ migrated | default(false) | bool | ternary('True', 'False') }}"`

or is there a way to run setup module keeping the gather_facts: False before calling the roles

Comment: Please do not multiply questions on the same subject or choose where to answer. I already replied to this in a comment in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272569/how-to-run-setup-module-before-calling-ansible-roles)

Comment: Thanks I got it, but as i am using rds endpoint then again I face the issue where true or false has to be assigned to a variable. I am unable to understand. Let me try out this code the way you have suggested.