# How can I explicitely run the setup module before calling ansible roles when gather_facts is false?

Tags: ansible

I want to set `gather_facts` to `false` but then use the `setup` module to gather facts and run the roles afterwards.

My code looks like:

```yaml
---
- name: RDS check
  hosts: "{{ run_on_node|default('cdh[0]')}}"
  gather_facts: False

  setup: #not sure about the indentation, but want to execute that before roles.
  roles:
    - { role: r1, when: "'10.200.1.197' in inventory_hostname" }
```

Comment: See [`pre_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setup` module has to be executed in a task section. `pre_tasks` are executed before `roles`.

Try as below:

```yaml
---
- name: RDS check
  hosts: "{{ run_on_node|default('cdh[0]')}}"
  gather_facts: False
 
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Gather facts
    setup: 

  roles:
    - { role: r1, when: "'10.200.1.197' in inventory_hostname" }
```

Comment: Done. I am new to SO in terms of posting questions. So just trying to get familiar with that.